# what is the way of overriding a method in some code

Tags: c++, overriding

Suppose we have the following code:

```
 class Base
    {
    public:
    virtual void foo() const 
    { cout << "In Base::foo\n"; }
    }

    class Derived : public Base
    {public:
    virtual void foo() 
    { cout << "In Derived::foo\n"; }
    }

    void main()
    {
     Base* b = new Derived();
     b->foo();
     delete b;
    }
```

It will give us the following output: `In Base::foo`.

Now suppose I want to get - without changing the main function - the follwing output instead the one given above:

```
In Derived::foo
```

As far as I understand, I should override the function **foo()**  of in the base, to get the output of the method 
**foo()** in the inheriting class which is class 'Derived'. 
But the problem is that in that case I can't using the command `override`, becuase the method in the base is defined as constant , which in the other class it is not.

So, how should I if then overriding that method ?

Comment: The shown code is undefined behavior. Delete of a derived class via base pointer without a virtual destructor.

Comment: Not to mention `void main()` And the lack of a semicolon at the end of the classes.

Comment: `Derived::foo()` needs to have EXACTLY the same signature as `Base::foo()`.   In your code, `Base::foo()` is `const` and `Derived::foo()` is not, so they have different signatures.     If you are going to use operator `new` and `delete` as you are, then `Base` also needs a `virtual` destructor, otherwise `delete b` has undefined behaviour.  Also `main()` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Use `override`, that's how you KNOW that you are overriding a virtual function. It's the only way. If you need a non const method, then you have a design problem, go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - using `override` is not the only way.   It is a safer way (assuming C++11 and later) since it increases chances of problems being diagnosed by the compiler.

Comment: @Peter That's how you can ensure that you are overriding a virtual function. You could add other fancy stuff, but that's the only reliable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override the function `void foo() const` of the base class, you must declare the function `void foo() const` in the derived class. You've declared the function `void foo()` instead (note the lack of `const`), which doesn't override the function in the base, because it has a different declaration.

> So, how should I if then overriding that method ?

Add the missing `const` qualifier.

---

P.S. Few other bugs in your program:

- `main` must return `int`.
- Class definitions must end in a semicolon.
- Deleting a derived object through a pointer to base has undefined behaviour unless the destructor of the base is virtual.

Comment: Thank you @eerorika , I appreciate your explanation.